# Content tag is not loading when i add a asp.net web page with master page (master page having two master page

Tags: asp.net

Someone please look at this issue.

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Nested.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index2.aspx.cs" Inherits="XYZ.Admin.AdminDashboard.Index2" %>
```

Comment: What???????????

Comment: i have one master page named XYZ and XYZ contain one more mater page name ABC. when i add web page using XYZ master page then <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server"> is not load in the web page. please help me. thank you.

Comment: following tags are not comming with page <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>   after <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Nested.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index2.aspx.cs" Inherits="XYZ.Admin.AdminDashboard.Index2" %>

Comment: i got the solution here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745449/content-controls-have-to-be-top-level-controls-in-a-content-page-or-a-nested-mas